# Add HTML formatting in phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHP mailer to send an online form directly to email.  I want to edit the form like this:

```
$message = '<p>The following request was sent from: '</p>;
$message .= '<p>Name: '.$name.'</p><br />';
$message .= '<p>Phone: '.$phone.'</p><br />';
$message .= '<p>Email: '.$email.'</p><br />';
```

However, in the email I receive back, I get the `<p>`, `<br />`, etc.  Not the formatting I want, but the actual HTML.  It has always worked for me, then I realized I was using the stock PHP mail function.  not sure if PHP mailer has different parameters OR if I just missing small here?

**Where would I set the headers for text/html?**

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail -> IsSMTP();
    $mail -> Host = "---";
    $mail -> Port = 25;
    $mail -> SMTPAuth = false;
    $mail -> Username = EMAIL_USER;
    $mail -> Password = EMAIL_PASS;
    $mail -> FromName = $from_name;
    $mail -> From = $from;
    $mail -> Subject = $subject;
    $mail -> Body = $message;
    $mail -> AddAddress("---");

    $result = $mail -> Send();
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### By default, the PHP `mail()` function is `text/plain`.

In your `mail()` headers, change the `content-type` to `text/html` and try.

#### Example:

```
<?php 
    $body = "<html>\n"; 
    $body .= "<body style=\"font-family:Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666666;\">\n"; 
    $body = $message; 
    $body .= "</body>\n"; 
    $body .= "</html>\n"; 

    $headers  = "From: My site<noreply@example.com>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: info@example.com\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Return-Path: info@example.com\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: Drupal\n"; 
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

    return mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers); 
?>
```

#### PHP Mailer:

You need to set `IsHTML(true)`:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Comment: Show your PHP `mail()` function declaration. Or see my updated answer. :)

Comment: Ok, I'm not using the php mail function, but now that I think about it, when I do I ALWAYS make sure to put text/html.  in the OO PHPHmailer, I dont see where I set this.  I will add my code to show you what I have.

Comment: Set `IsHTML(true)` in PHP Mailer.

Comment: I see that in the body of the email, you're including the HTML and BODY tags. Is that necessary when sending an email? Good practice? As of right now I'm just styling the body without html and body tags.

Answer (score 49):

In PHP mailer, you need to set below

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Note: `$mail` means your PHPMailer object.

Reference Link: [PHPMailer](http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/send-mail-using-phpmailer-en/)