# phpmailer body, want to use html and php

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I am trying to build a verification mail for my website, but I can't seem to get the PHPmailer to include html and php. I can get the verification mail send to the correct mail address, with the correct body, the code for that is this:

```
$mail->Body = 'Please verificate your account by clicking on the following link: http:localhost/confirm.php?passkey=' . $confirm_code;
```

Now I am trying to get the link in the mail to be an actual link, I tried this (see code below) but that didn't work

```
$mail->Body = 'Please verificate your account by clicking on the following link: <a href=\"http:localhost/confirm.php?passkey= . $confirm_code\">http:localhost/confirm.php?passkey=' . $confirm_code . '</a>';
```

I have set the PHPmailer to send emails with html:

```
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
```

Could anyone tell me what the problem is here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789989/add-html-formatting-in-phpmailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `Debugoutput` has nothing to do with sending HTML - it's the error output format. You need to call `isHTML()` or set your content using `msgHTML()`. Also there is no such word as 'verificate' it's just 'verify'.

Comment: I already figured out the ishtml (see comment above) but thanks for the correction in English, it is not my native tongue, so I still make mistakes sometimes ;)

Comment: It just made you sound like George W Bush!

Answer (score 1):

You have to concatenate the link var too.

Also, within single quotes you don't need to use backslash:

```
$mail->Body = 'Please verificate your account by clicking on the following link: <a href="http:localhost/confirm.php?passkey='. $confirm_code.'">http:localhost/confirm.php?passkey=' . $confirm_code . '</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I for it to work I also needed this code added:    $mail->IsHTML(true);