# Send mail using PHP form as HTML (not plain text)

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

I need to send e-mail from a web form.
Received email must be displayed as HTML, not text.

```
 function createMailBodyLine ( $title, $value ) {
            $value = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($value));
            return "<tr><td style='vertical-align:top; text-align:right; color:#666666; padding-right:10px;'>{$title}:</td><td>{$value}</td></tr>";
        }

        $from = ins_lgrb('contacts_email', null, true);

        $to   = 'xx@xxv.lv;xx@xxv.lv';

        $subj = ' sssssssss';

           $body  = "<html><head><title>sssssssss</title></head><body>";
        $body .= "Jauna ziņa <br/><br/>";
        $body .= "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
        $body .= createMailBodyLine('Vārds, uzvārds', $_POST['name_surname']);
        $body .= createMailBodyLine('E-pasta adrese', $_POST['mail']);
        $body .= createMailBodyLine('Pasta adrese'  , $_POST['address']);
        $body .= createMailBodyLine('Sūtītāja IP'   , $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $body .= createMailBodyLine('Laiks'         , date('d.m.Y, H:i:s', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']));
        $body .= createMailBodyLine('Jautājums'     , $_POST['question']);
        $body .= "</table></body></html>";

        mb_send_mail($to, $subj, $body, "From: {$from}, nMIME-Version: 1.0nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8n");

        reload();
    }
    savePost();
```

Dispalys all html code when wiewed in email, body like this:

```
<html><head><title>Jauna ziņa </title></head><body>Jauna ziņa<br/><br/><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td style='vertical-align:top; text-align:right; color:#666666; padding-right:10px;'>Vārds, uzvārds:</td><td></td></tr><tr><td style='vertical-align:top; text-align:right; color:#6666.....d></tr></table></body></html>
```

Something goes wrong with : `htmlspecialchars` ?

Comment: set headers, $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a header error. Remove the "n" before "MIME" and see if it works.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-send-mail.php

Answer (score 0):

In the `$headers` parameter to your `mb_send_mail` call, you are not delimiting your `Content-type` header from everything else. Try using this:

```
"From: {$from}, \r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can switch to php mailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
phpmailer has all email related readymate functions to set email as html
you can use $mail->IsHTML(true);
read [Add HTML formatting in phpmailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789989/add-html-formatting-in-phpmailer)