# Php how to send mail with bold text

Tags: php

Here I am trying to send the email with some text highlighted in bold.
Here is what I have tried but I am getting the tags as it is but I am not getting the bold font. How can I do this?

Here is what I have done:

```
$mail->Body = PROPOSE_STATEMENT." <b>".$product_name."</b> ".REJECTED;
```

Here I have used the html `<b></b>` tags in the php to make the text bold but I am getting output like this:

```
 you proposed <b>TVS Apache RTR 160</b> Has been
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add HTML formatting in phpmailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789989/add-html-formatting-in-phpmailer)

Comment: The output needs to be sent AS html, Meaning you need to send some info along in the headers telling the e-mail reader or w.e it's called that the content is to be read as HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 
**PHP Maile**r then add this line in your script

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Comment: $mail->MsgHTML() is also a option

Answer (score 5):

You have to send an HTML Mail.
Set to, subject and headers (Set HTML in header)

```
$to = 'bob@example.com';
$subject = 'Request'; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
//Set the content-type to html
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Now you can use HTML

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1><b>bold</b>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
```

And send the Mail

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the HTML content type in the email header

```
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"
```

Your code doesnt indicate some standard email sending method that im aware of so i cant help with actual code

Answer (score 1):

There's a really good answer about this in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789989/add-html-formatting-in-phpmailer) which covers general HTML formatting.

You pretty much either need to set the content type of the e-mail by doing:

`Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

or, if using PHP mailer, use the following to set the e-mail to be HTML:

`$mail->IsHTML(true);`